# IIS web URL redirect to subfolder over http to https different port

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, webserver, iis-7.5

I am using IIS 7.5 in my server for the webserver.
request your support for the URL redirection from HTTP to HTTPS.
My HTTP service is running on the 80 port and the HTTPS is running on the 4545 port. due to the port change getting problem.

also please help me to redirect from the root folder to the subfolder on the 4545 port.

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this URL Rewrite Rule:

```
    <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="HTTPS Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://localhost:4545/..." appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

The URL part of this rule needs to be modified by yourself.